# Can I deal with vector fields in sympy without specifying coordinate system?

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I have differential equations for two vector fields: diffusion equation for magnetic field and Navier-Stokes equation for fluid velocity. I am interested in transformation of these equations without specifying coordinate system. Sympy.vector gives opportunity to deal with vector fields, but I need to specify each component of vector. I understand that when you deal with nabla operator symbolicaly (without specifying coordinate system) it can be confusing. For example, [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLNfv.jpg). But maybe there is another class in sympy or another package in python that can deal in that way?

Comment: `sympy.vector` allows to work with explicit vectors, that is, vectors where you specify the components. Sadly, SymPy doesn't have any capability to deal with "vector expressions", which is what you are looking for.